# v-model и ckeditor проблема связывания

Tags: ckeditor, vue.js

Работаю с ckeditor и vue на laravel 5.4. При попытке свзяи через v-model простой textarea работает без проблем, но стоит прицепить ckeditor и все... Использовал данный код, который нашёл на просторах stackoverflow:

```
Vue.nextTick(function () {
    $('textarea.editor').each(function(){
        CKEDITOR.replace(this.id);
    });
});
```

Входные данные отображаются, но нет результата редактирования (т.е. связанная модель не видит изменений). 
Так же видел отдельный пакет `vue-ckeditor2`, но не нашёл как добавить в него все компоненты ckeditor(из описания совсем скудный набор)... Есть ли "правильное" решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно либо создать [директиву](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) новую, либо отслеживать событие изменения ckeditor, при помощи события on change, тут пример того, как прилетают данные, подставляются в редактор и отслеживается изменение через переменную page.content в моделе

```
mounted() {
            var self = this;
            this.$http.get(this.url).then(
                (response)=>{
                    self.page = response.data.page;
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'content', {
                        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
                        filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token='+window.Laravel.csrfToken,
                        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files',
                        filebrowserUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Files&_token='+window.Laravel.csrfToken,
                        on:{
                            'change': function(event) {
                               self.page.content = event.editor.getData();
                               self.updateContent = true;
                            }
                        }
                      }).setData(self.page.content);
                },
                (response)=>{
                }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но сейчас на другом проекте и нет времени проверить! Но скоро вернусь к этому вопросу и, если все верно, отмечу ваш вопрос и плюсану)